# Golang for seems to be skipping some entities

Tags: go

So I have an `out` string like this:

```golang
out := 
    "mobile" + "\n" + 
    "mobile/communicators" + "\n" + 
    "mobile/communicators/mock" + "\n" + 
    "mobile/handlers" + "\n" + 
    "mobile/mocks" + "\n" + 
    "mobile/models" + "\n" + 
    "mobile/requests"
```

Which I'm trying to transform into a slice and then remove the entries which have matching sub-strings in the `pkgsToIgnore` slice:

```golang
pkgs := strings.Split(strings.TrimSpace(string(out)), "\n")

pkgsToIgnore := []string{"mock", "models"}

for i, pkg := range pkgs {
    for _, pkgToIgnore := range pkgsToIgnore {
        if strings.Contains(pkg, pkgToIgnore){
            pkgs = append(pkgs[:i], pkgs[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
}

for _, pkg := range pkgs {
    fmt.Println(pkg)
}
```

And then this is the result I get from the `Println` iterations:

```
mobile
mobile/communicators
mobile/handlers
mobile/models
mobile/requests
```

My code seems to work fine for the lines containing `mock` as a sub-string, as they get removed. But I can't understand why `mobile/models` doesn't.

Comment: You should **NOT** modify `pkgs` as you are `range`ing through it. Copy the items to another list and have pointer to the original list instead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see what is happening is to output `i` and `pkg` during each iteration i.e.

```
for i, pkg := range pkgs {
        fmt.Println(i, pkg)
        for _, pkgToIgnore := range pkgsToIgnore {
            if strings.Contains(pkg, pkgToIgnore) {
                pkgs = append(pkgs[:i], pkgs[i+1:]...)
            }
        }
    }
```

The [output of this](https://play.golang.org/p/4sBjStLp4m6) is:

```
0 mobile
1 mobile/communicators
2 mobile/communicators/mock
3 mobile/mocks
4 mobile/requests
5 mobile/requests
6 mobile/requests
```

This is probably not what you were expecting! The reason for that is that you are removing elements from `pkgs` whilst iterating over it. Lets work through this when i = 2; `pkg` == "mobile/communicators/mock" so the string will be removed from `pkgs`. Element 2 of `pkgs` is now "mobile/handlers". We loop around to the `for` and move to the next element (3) which is "mobile/mocks" (not "mobile/handler" - that is now element 2 so "mobile/handler" does not get checked).

The relevant section of the [go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range) may help in understanding this:

> For an array, pointer to array, or slice value a, the index iteration
> values are produced in increasing order, starting at element index 0.
> If at most one iteration variable is present, the range loop produces
> iteration values from 0 up to len(a)-1 and does not index into the
> array or slice itself. For a nil slice, the number of iterations is 0.

It is possible to update a slice within a loop like this but doing so [requires care](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#filter-in-place); generally its simpler to copy the elements you want to keep into a new slice.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this without accidentally skipping elements. One way is simply to copy the elements you want into a temporary slice and then replace the original once you've done everything (it's much harder to make mistakes that way). But if you don't like that, it helps to use *two* indices:

```
src, dst := 0, 0
for src < len(pkgs) {
    var ignored bool
    for _, pkgToIgnore := range pkgsToIgnore {
        if strings.Contains(pkg, pkgToIgnore) {
            ignored = true
            break
        }
    }
    if !ignored {
        pkgs[dst] = pkgs[src]
        dst += 1
    }
    src += 1
}

pkgs = pkgs[:dst]
```

`src` will range from 0 to the last index of `pkgs`; `dst` will always be less than or equal to `src` (so we never overwrite an element we haven't seen yet); each element is only copied once, to its final destination, instead of shifting all elements left by one each time an element is removed (which is potentially quadratic). The length of the slice is only adjusted at the end, to reflect the number of elements actually retained.